# Downloading text instead of render (probably Nginx conf)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my app to VPS (Rails 3.2, capistrano 2.15)

Ubuntu 13.10 + Nginx 1.4.7 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.40

I was following these manuals

http://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/12.04 and
https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic

Had some problems in configuring Nginx as I never used it before (403 err, 500 err etc)

Eventually I got very weird thing which makes me nuts:
when I go to URL where my app is supposed to be (and a normal html page is supposed to be rendered) I get a text file downloaded instead. This text file contains my ruby code (like in code of /home/myapp/current/app/views/home/index.html.haml).

Here is what my /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf contains

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/passenger-4$
    passenger_ruby /home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

# access_log  logs/access.log main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       111.111.111.111:80;
    server_name  myserver.linode.com www.myserver.linode.com
    rails_env production;
    root /home/myapp/current/app/views/home;
    passenger_enabled on;
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    index   index.html index.htm index.html.haml;
    charset utf-8;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl                  on;
#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
    }
}
```

I also tried to remove the line
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
and after that code of /home/myapp/current/app/views/home/index.html.haml was rendered when I opened the root URL in browser. Ahaha!

What is wrong?

thank you in advance)

Comment: There is a typo in the configuration, `nclude       mime.types;` should be `include       mime.types;`. But Nginx should warn you about this. The other thing I noticed is that the root is wrong, it should point to the root directory of Rails. So change `root /home/myapp/current/app/views/home;` to `root /home/myapp/current;`

Comment: have changed, and know I get 403 Forbidden. "Include": yep, it's a typo here, fixed

Comment: And what happens if you change root to `root /home/myapp/current/public;`?

Comment: Actually I do understand why 403 happens. I have had set roots neither to "current" nor to "public". I set a root to index inside the folder initially mentioned. That's why I get Fobidden err when change the path as it's really forbidden. I don't understand why it's not working when I put the correct path

Comment: Well, what is in `config/routes.rb`? You need to create a root route there: `root to: 'home#index'`. Do you have a home controller? Also, what's the URL you are trying to access the page? You should just use http://myserver.linode.com (or whatever is configured), not http://myserver.linode.com/app/views/home/index.html.haml.

Comment: My app is working perfectly at my local server. Thanks for your advice yet I do have all of that.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem then. What you could do is to check whether the user used by Passenger has read and execute permission on `/home/myapp/current`. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.